# what is the purpose of using the `from exc` in `raise RuntimeError('Failed to open database') from exc`?

Tags: python

https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html#exception-chaining

```
>>>
>>> def func():
...     raise IOError
...
>>> try:
...     func()
... except IOError as exc:
...     raise RuntimeError('Failed to open database') from exc
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in func
OSError

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
RuntimeError: Failed to open database
```

Exception chaining happens automatically when an exception is raised inside an except or finally section. So what is the purpose of using the `from exc` in `raise RuntimeError('Failed to open database') from exc`? Isn't it implicit?

Comment: The link just under this section: "For more information about chaining mechanics, see [Built-in Exceptions](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#bltin-exceptions) gives more detailed explanations. You might want to tell us more accurately what part of this you find unclear.

Comment: Chaining happens if you just say `raise`.  In this case, it is raising a different exception from what it caught, so the "from" is needed.  Otherwise, this would be a brand-new exception.

Comment: Tim - it says that Exception chaining happens automatically when an exception is raised inside an except or finally section.

Answer (score 0):

You can always check the PEP which introduces a feature. In this case, you may read this section of [PEP 3141](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3134/#explicit-exception-chaining).

The use of the syntax `raise EXCEPTION from CAUSE` allows for an explicit chaining of exceptions. Like in the example given on that page, if you want to raise only a certain error in an API, but also want to highlight the original exception raising the issue, you can use this way of chaining exceptions.

So it just offers a more explicit way of doing that, while the "normal" syntax `raise EXCEPTION` only implicitly chains the exceptions.

Is this understandable? Let me know if you don't understand it.

Comment: So in my question example code, is `from exc` optional?

Comment: Yes. It is always optional.